# Unable to render videos using XML parser

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser, ios5, sigabrt

This is my implementation, I have initialized all the properties and outlets in the header file of course. I am new to Xcode and Obj-c programming and trying to play this videos on the iOS5 simulator, which is not working. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

```
#import "VideoMainViewController.h"
#import "HotdogAppDelegate.h"
#import "Video.h"

@implementation VideoMainViewController
@synthesize videoArray; 
@synthesize currentCateogry;
@synthesize secondView;
@synthesize thumbContainerView;

NSXMLParser *xmlParser;

-(VideoMainViewController *) initWithXML{
self.videoArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
self.secondView = [[VideoSecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:thumbView];


NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videos" ofType:@"xml"];   
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[xmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onVideoBackClick) name:@"onVideoBack" object:self.secondView];

HotdogAppDelegate *application = (HotdogAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[application addViewController:&self];
[super init];
return self;
}


-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}

 -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; 
  }

-(void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
}

-(IBAction) onMayoClick:(id)sender{
[self.secondView loadVideos:(NSMutableArray *)[self.videoArray objectAtIndex:0]];
}
-(IBAction) onMustardClick:(id)sender{
[self.secondView loadVideos:(NSMutableArray *)[self.videoArray objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
   -(IBAction) onKetchupClick:(id)sender{
[self.secondView loadVideos:(NSMutableArray *)[self.videoArray objectAtIndex:2]];
    }

    -(void)stopVideo{
[secondView stopVideo];
    }

    -(void) reset{
[self.view addSubview:thumbView];
thumbView.alpha = 1;
if(self.secondView.view.superview){
[self.secondView.view removeFromSuperview];
}
    }


   -(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
[xmlParser release];
    }

    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
     namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Mayo"]||
   [elementName isEqualToString:@"Mustard"]||
   [elementName isEqualToString:@"Ketchup"]) {  

    self.currentCateogry = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    [self.videoArray addObject:self.currentCateogry];

}else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
    Video *video = [[Video alloc] init];
    video.thumb = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"thumb"];
    video.mp4 = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"mp4"];
    video.title = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"title"];

    [self.currentCateogry addObject:video];

}
    }

   -(void) dealloc{ 

for (NSObject *video in self.videoArray) {
    [video dealloc];
}

[self.videoArray removeAllObjects];
[self.videoArray dealloc];
[self.secondView dealloc];
[xmlParser dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
    }


    @end
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Videos usually wont play in the simulator.  You may need to run it on an actual device to see the video play properly.

---

Also, try setting [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: Either ways ..I seem to getting a program received sigabrt message in my main thread... the debugger doesn't say much... but im wondering if there is an error in this line of code       (VideoMainViewController *) initWithXML{
self.videoArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

Comment: thanks, I did a stack trace and the line it points to is below. Although I don't know what the error could be.                                                        `[self.view addSubview:thumbView];`

Comment: Try changing it to `self.videoArray = [NSMutableArray array];`.  There no real need to init with a capacity anyway.

Comment: Nope. I read somewhere that arrayWithCapacity was not necessary so tried that already.. the app crashes in the main thread with a message **thread 1 program received signal sigabrt** although I have linked everything in the interface builder and .xib file.. so I wonder why I am getting this message.

Comment: You could also try putting `NSLog(@"%@", thumbView);` just before `[self.view addSubview:thumbView];` to make sure it is not `nil`?

Comment: -Oops, thumbView is null, but I fixed that. Thanks, but app still crashes with sigabrt.